# WebClient gets 401 when requesting a directory without a slash

Tags: https, webclient, basic-authentication, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-401

I have a web server using nginx, configured with HTTPS and Basic Authentication.

I'm attempting to query it with my WebClient with PowerShell

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = Get-Credential
return $wc.DownloadString($url)
```

This works fine with the following `$url`s

```
https://server.com
https://server.com/
https://server.com/directory/
https://server.com/page.php
https://server.com/directory/index.php
```

But for the following `$url`s, I get `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

```
https://server.com/directory
https://server.com/otherdirectory
https://server.com/directory/directory
```

I thought at first it was due to redirection, but that wouldn't make sense given some of the working examples. Perhaps it's my nginx configuration?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: It gets a 401, as per the title. Probably should have mentioned that in the body of my question - updated now thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour when you navigate with an ordinary browser? It seems very likely that the problem is with the setup of the web server/web application. You could do an internet search on `nginx trailing slash` or similar, to find ways to configure nginx for handle this the way you want. I found several promising links from a quick search using those keywords. Best of luck!

Comment: no, it works fine in the browser

Comment: aha, but the browser redirects to give a slash. how did i not notice this before

Comment: I believe this is a bug in `WebClient`. After receiving a 401, and then subsequently a 301, it does not send the Auth token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently believe this is a bug in the `WebClient` class. Here is a summary of my interactions with the server:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /directory HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 02:37:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 203
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="sup"

<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /directory HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic bmFjaHQ6aGVsbG8=
Host: example.com
------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 02:37:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 193
Location: http://example.com/directory/
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /directory/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 02:37:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 203
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="sup"

<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

At this point, the WebClient throws an exception, stating that the server returns the error stated in the question.

It should probably provide the auth token with the third request, or at the very least respond to the 401 with another request with the auth token provided.

I would like to have this confirmed by someone else (preferably with .NET 4.5.2) so I can accept this as the answer.